# dereference a pointer -vs- &-operator

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dereference

Would these two assignments be equivalent, i.e. perfom exactly the same thing?

```
*pointer = object

pointer = &object
```

, where pointer is a pointer to an "object-instance".

Or does this only make sense for primitive types.

Comment: They are definitely *VERY* different. You have to read more (and experiment) about pointers.

Comment: This is one of those things that are much easier to understand if you pull out a pencil and some paper and *draw* what happens using boxes and arrows. IMO, pencil and paper are the best tools for solving most pointer-related problems.

Comment: yeah you're right. should have thought it through before posting I guess. Thanks for tips though!

Comment: As bool expressions, `*pointer == object` and `pointer == &object` are quite similar though. It might be a good exercise to explain any differences there.

Answer (score 13):

No, these are not the same.

`pointer = &object` sets `pointer` so that it points at `object`.

`*pointer = object` sets the value of thing being pointed to by `pointer` to be equal to the value of `object`.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not.

```
*pointer = object
```

changes the memory the pointer points to.

```
pointer = &object
```

changes the pointer.

```
pointer   ---->    object1
&object   ---->    object
```

In the first case, this becomes:

```
pointer   ---->    object
&object   ---->    object
```

In the second case:

```
                  ---->    object1 //could turn into a memory leak
&object, pointer  ---->    object
```

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not equivalent.  The first makes the target value of the pointer equal to the object on the right hand side.  The second changes the pointer itself so that it points at the object on the right side.

In other words, after the first, there are two objects in memory with values equal to `object`'s value.  After the second, there is only one object with that value, and additionally there's a pointer pointing at that object.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

your first expression assigns the value of object to pointer.

suppose your pointer variable points to 0x1234. after the first assignment the address 0x1234 will contain value "object".

whereas second assignment will make the pointer to point to the address of object.

if you change the value object after first assignment pointer won't notice anything.

where as second  assignment, if you change the value of object, you can get the updated value through

```
*pointer.
```